# (PyQtGraph) How can I remove 'History' and 'Exceptions' buttons on a console widget?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I can make a console widget with the following command:

`console = pyqtgraph.console.ConsoleWidget(namespace=namespace, text='test', historyFile=None, editor=None)`

But how can I remove 'History' and 'Exceptions' buttons that are basically created? I referred to this page(http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/consolewidget.html), but I couldn't find how.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the buttons by their `objectName`: "exceptionBtn", "historyBtn" and then delete it with `deleteLater()`

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph.console

app = pg.mkQApp()
namespace = {'pg': pg, 'np': np}

## initial text to display in the console
text = """
This is an interactive python console. The numpy and pyqtgraph modules have already been imported 
as 'np' and 'pg'. 

Go, play.
"""
console = pyqtgraph.console.ConsoleWidget(namespace=namespace, text=text, historyFile=None, editor=None)
[console.findChild(QtGui.QPushButton, name).deleteLater() for name in ("exceptionBtn", "historyBtn")]
console.show()
console.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ConsoleWidget')

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Output:

[image]